# how to return boolean value in controller with $http.get

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So i would like to return boolean value in my controller. Only I would like to do is try to use it with `ng-show` / `ng-hide` when boolean is `true` / `false` to hide content not desired for normal user but for admin only. This is my code:

parts of my `adminController.js`:

```
.constant("userUrl", "http://localhost:5500/users/type")
.controller("typeCtrl", function($scope, $http, userUrl) {
    $http.get(userUrl, {withCredentials : true})
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });
    $scope.thisUser;
})
```

part of my `admin.html` i would like to use the value for example :

```
<div ng-show="thisUser == true" class="col-xs-3 panel-body">
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

I am beginning with angular and can't return the value of "type" in my resource "users" to put it in the view from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like:

```
$http.get(userUrl, {withCredentials : true})
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    })

<div ng-show="user.type == 'admin'" class="col-xs-3 panel-body">
```

Comment: Shall i than call my entity in resources, I mean the boolean one as "admin" or may it still be called "type"?

Comment: if the value is boolean, it will be better to have a property name like 'isAdmin' and in template, it should be ng-show="user.isAdmin"

Comment: So may i ask You one more question which line actually does return the boolean value now in my controller? $scope.user = data; ?

Comment: There is no line that returns a boolean value and there is no need to return anything. The object user (that is also the result data of your http call) should have a property of type boolen (we called  this property 'type' or 'isAdmin' ). Because the objet user is attached to $scope (by the assignement $scope.user = data), user.isAdmin (or user.type) can be used in template (<div ng-show="user.isAdmin></div>)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand :) Cheers !